# pointer-event: none; not work on iOS safari

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, sass

```css
.a {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.b {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="a" (click)="goWebSite()">
  text-a
</div>

<div class="b" (click)="goWebSite()">
  <span>text-b</span>
</div>
```

What is the diffrent between 'class a' and 'class b'?

Why class a, point-event not work on iOS...?

It works fine on Android and PC Chrome.

I am not good at English, so the sentences may be strange. sorry.

Comment: what version? check [canIUse](https://caniuse.com/pointer)

Comment: iOS 15.6 version

Comment: its saying its supported, could you try adding `!important`

Comment: Your code 'translated' to pure HTML works find on IOS 15.6.1 for me so could you inspect the code that angular is producing and show us the actual HTML and CSS.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with sketchy pointer-events issues on safari - did you end up figuring out what is up?  Apple products are so buggy...